# Getting an UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

I have these two methods:

```java
public void addMappedListField(String collector) {
  EntityField field = new EntityField(collector.toLowerCase(), collector,
    RelationEnum.MANY_TO_ONE);
  field.setRealType(collector); // TODO: Fix this error
  if (fields == null)
    fields = new ArrayList<>();
  this.fields.add(field);
}
```

```java
public static void generateMappedFields(List<Entity> entities) { 
  entities.forEach(entity -> {
    if (entity.fields != null)
      entity.fields.stream()
        .filter(field -> field.getRelation() == RelationEnum.ONE_TO_MANY)
        .forEach(field -> entities.stream()
          .filter(en -> Objects.equals(en.getName(), field.getListType()))
          .forEach(e -> e.addMappedListField(entity.getName())));
  });
}
```

It throw this err

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)    
  at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.add(ImmutableCollections.java:147)
  at org.bsh.classes.Entity.addMappedListField(Entity.java:55)
  at org.bsh.classes.Entity.lambda$generateMappedFields$2(Entity.java:66)   
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
  at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:722)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
  at org.bsh.classes.Entity.lambda$generateMappedFields$3(Entity.java:66)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
  at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:722)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
  at org.bsh.classes.Entity.lambda$generateMappedFields$4(Entity.java:63)
  at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
  at org.bsh.classes.Entity.generateMappedFields(Entity.java:59)
  at org.bsh.yaml_reader.config_clases.AppConfig.getGenerateEntities(AppConfig.java:29)
  at org.bsh.Main.fetchData(Main.java:23)
  at org.bsh.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

How can i fix this erro

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the code and error properly.

Comment: What about know

Comment: Since I do not know which line `Entity.java:55` is, I am going to guess and say that `this.fields` is an `ImmutableList`. Hence the exception.

Comment: Yeah the line is `this.fields.add(field)`

Comment: Then `this.fields` is an `ImmutableList`.

Comment: So how can i add the field to the list

Comment: Don't use an `ImmutableList`.

Comment: @Hamza You can't. It's immutable. You can make a new list and assign that to `this.fields`. But more likely whatever is making `this.fields` be an immutable field should be changed so that it no longer is. Without more code we can't really help you here.

Comment: Please include the code that sets `this.fields`

Comment: By adding the fileds element to ArrayList